# YouTube Analytics for Actionscript 3 YouTube Chromeless Player

Tags: actionscript, youtube, youtube-api, analytics, chromeless

I am using the YouTube ActionScript 3.0 API, the Chromeless Player to embed a YouTube video from a YouTube Channel in a Flash Ad.

So, once the Ad has been served, I want to know if I will have data in YouTube Analytics for the video embeded.

I have made some trials but I´m not sure about the results. Maybe the Player must be user initiated to have stats

By now the data I am really interested to have in YouTube Analytics are:
- Playback locations
- Traffic Sources

YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API Reference
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference?hl=en

Comment: As seen on https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#playVideo:  

"The definition of the playVideo function has been updated to note that YouTube only counts playbacks that are initiated through a native play button in either the embedded or chromeless player."

so, When a YT video is embedded, whether its by js, chromeless player or simple html, the view will not be counted unless the viewer interact with a "Native YT  Player Play button".  That's why views don't get counted on the dynamic load if they have Autoplay.

Comment: Also here, in the YouTube player component Build Guide, http://motifcdn2.doubleclick.net/EMEA/ad-in-a-box/YTP/DCRM_YouTube_Player_Component_EN.pdf is says: "IMPORTANT:. YouTube video views will ONLY count if a user interacts with the default YouTube play button
which appears in the middle of the creative or the play button on the default control menu in the bottom left corner
of the player. Autoplay videos will not count."

Comment: YouTube public video play count
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2566092?hl=en
The YouTube Video Player allows masthead video views to count directly toward overall YouTube brand channel video views. For the YouTube view to count, the user must click to start the video using the standard YouTube play button. Autoplay videos don’t count toward YouTube views.